# DRF - adding depth=1 to model serializer no longer allows me to POST

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have a simple serializer:

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = [field.name for field in model._meta.fields]
        # depth = 1
        extra_kwargs = {'created_by': {'default': serializers.CurrentUserDefault()}}
```

Which works both ways - I can list `Order`s and I can create an `Order`.

As you see there is `created_by` set to default user which works without specifying `depth`. When I specify `depth` when creating an object, `DRF` returns error:

> null value in column "created_by_id" violates not-null constraint

I know that it's because now, the `created_by` is serialized as `user` but don't know how to make it work when creating objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you get this error is because depth is an attribute for read serializers. For example

a nested representation using your serializer with depth of 1 would look like

```
{ 'order_id': 1
  'created_by': { {'id': 1, 'name': 'hello', 'email': 'foo@bar.com'} } 
} # created_by object is fully serialized and not just the id
```

Now that makes sense for read but when posting to the endpoint using your serializer with depth 1, the client would need to post the full user object (it won't do it implicitly. you would need to implement the custom logic that says find this user object and assign it on POST. And additional code for PATCH and PUT. This just wouldn't be recommended)

**You have a few options**

1. What I recommend is using 2 different serializers for read and create.
2. You can maintain the same serializer and omit the depth attr, allowing you to post and read to it but will need to make an additional http request from the client for the entire user object.
3. You can get creative and implement some logic that changes the depth depending on the http method.

Comment: Very well explained..thank you...simple is better...yet again proved.